# SP13 - Calendar Permissions

Tags: 2013, calendar

I have a calendar and I would like to allow end-users to add events to the calendar. However, I want them to be able to create, view, edit, and delete within their own events ONLY.  If I create another view from the calendar, would this give me my outcome?   Within that view I would set the view to equal [Me], correct?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: With views, you are not setting permissions rather just hiding items from the users. If they know their ways they can easily access all users items and delete them etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Advanced Settings for the calendar, you can specify

Read access:   Specify which items users are allowed to read
Create and Edit access:   Specify which items users are allowed to create and edit

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I followed the steps you mentioned, but other users can still edit my entries.  Do I make the changes in Advanced Settings and change the view settings to [Me]? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If users can still edit your events, can you confirm what security groups they're in? Note the note on the left, there are permission groups which override this setting. Also, if you want them to only see their own, you can filter it to read items that were created by the user. In addition, for those admins, you can create a [Me] view to help narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The security groups they are in is "contribute".  The idea I had was to create a [Me] view and connect the web part to a page and allow the end-user to work only off of that view.  Any thoughts?  I am trying to work around the fact that they have "contribute" permissions.  I am sorry.  I think I am making this harder, because it seems like a simple process. Thanks!

Comment: @Davidi Lozzi I was able to get it to work. The only that is not working properly is that all events are not appearing in the calendar.  In order to view all is to go to all events view.  If the read access in the advance settings, shouldn't the user be able to see everyone's but cannot edit, correct? Thanks

Comment: Correct, they should be able to read all items, and only edit their own if you match the above. did you update the view to filter by [Me]?

Comment: Okay. Something must be off some where else.  I matched the above screen shot but other users cannot see all of the entries (or entries that are not their own) in the "grid" view but can see in "all items" view.  I need to see it in both.  So, this may mean the permissions are off.  No, I haven't filter yet by [Me].  I was waiting until I was able for all users to see all event entries in the "grid" view. I probably doing something so simple incorrect. Thanks, David Lozzi for all of your help!

Comment: I'd create a new issue on the site for this item, let everyone see what's happening now ;) good luck!

Comment: I'm trying to do the same set up where as my users who create their event in the group calendar, can only edit or delete it. But upon going to Advance Settings, I only have Content Types and Attachments and the rest. No Item-level permission. Please advise